# DNN 5.0 Modules available for Free or less cost

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am just planning to work on CMS with some features like blog, forum, chat, broadcast, video, Document management, poll, dashboard, advertisement, alerts & reminder, events, task etc..

I am thinking of using DNN for development as i feel most of the modules are available so i just need to do the customization.

Also suggest what all are the modules available in core DNN (Community version)

is anybody is having list what all are the modules available for DNN 5.0 ?

Please provide the link for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started - http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-list/packagetypeid/2

Also if you want to buy to save time check out http://www.snowcovered.com - lots of third party modules there for sale - also on the forums you can pick up lots of people who have modules for download

Answer (score 0):

There is one very good social networking module available for DNN 5.X which is Vivo Social.
You can visit the site imvivo.com to see the demo and to download you can go to vivoware.com.
I have used on my portal and it has loads of features, many of you want

Regards